# Is it possible to upload the same file, to multiple document libraries?

Tags: document-library, permissions, security, file-upload, document-upload

Is it possible to quickly upload the same file to multiple document libraries? The reason I want to do this is because I have multiple document libraries because they each have different security groups/permissions. And some files need to be accessed by multiple security groups, so is it possible to do this, without having to do it manually?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**Is it possible to quickly upload the same file to multiple document libraries?**

Yes!

**is it possible to do this, without having to do it manually?**

No!

---

**In your case,** it's a big headache to achieve your requirements with this way, the recommended solution is to manage the permission on the item level by uploading one file to one document library and manage the permission for this file.

**Check** How to manage file permission at [SharePoint - managing file/folder-level permissions](https://www.as.uky.edu/tutorials/sharepoint-managing-filefolder-level-permissions)

Comment: Hi Mohamed, thank you! Would you recommend to do this at the folder level (for example create folders within the document libraries for the different groups), or using document sets (not sure what the difference is)?

Comment: Also, would you or have you ever done Sharepoint tutoring?